# How to delete "blank links"/"dead links" from Dash search?

Tags: unity, 12.10, unity-dash, netbeans

After removing the old version of Netbeans and installing the new version, I've being getting the problem. Looks like the Netbeans uninstaller removed everything related with it, except the link/shortcut, and now after I've installed the new version I always get two results in the Dash when I look for Netbeans (it also happens when I'm looking for it with the Applications Lens).

So, I'd like to know how to remove the "blank link" (that takes me nowhere when I click it).

Here is a printscreen/screenshot of the problem:

[image]
(Just click on it for the full resolution version)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Main Menu (`alacarte`). To install it you can search for `alacarte` in Ubuntu Software Center or from the command line with:

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

After installing it, look for "alacarte" or "Main Menu" on Dash, the following window will open:

[image]

1. Select an item to remove
2. Click on "Delete" to remove the item and click close.